# How to write helper in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, helper

I need to check is the current post in users favorites list

something like(in view):

```
if in_favorites?
  #remove link
else
  #add link
```

Where I must place helper's code in `application_controller.rb`, `current_controller#current_def`, `current_controller#custom_def` or in `application_helper.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this code would deal with posts, you should put it in `app/helpers/posts_helper.rb`